# optimize indexes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Order collection with records looking like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "status": String Enum,
    "products": [{
        "sku": String UUID,
        ...
    }, ...],
    ...
},
```

My goal is to find find what products user buy together. Given an sku, i would like to browse the past order and find, for orders that contains more than 1 product AND of course the product with the looked up sku, what other products were bought along.

So I created a aggregation pipeline that works :

```
[
    // exclude cancelled orders
  {
    '$match': {
      'status': {
        '$nin': [
          'CANCELLED', 'CHECK_OUT'
        ]
      }
    }
  },
// add a fields with product size and just the products sku
 {
    '$addFields': {
      'size': {
        '$size': '$products'
      }, 
      'skus': '$products.sku'
    }
  }, 
// limit to orders with 2 products or more including the looked up SKU
{
    '$match': {
      'size': {
        '$gte': 2
      }, 
      'skus': {
        '$elemMatch': {
          '$eq': '3516215049767'
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
// group by skus
{
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$skus'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$skus', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, 

// sort by count, exclude the looked up sku, limit to 4 results
{
$sort': {
      'count': -1
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '_id': {
        '$ne': '3516215049767'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$limit': 4
  }
]
```

Althought this works, this collection contains more than 10K docs and I have an alert on my MongoDB instance telling me than the ratio Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000.

So my question is, how can my query be improve? and what indexes can I add to improve this?

```
db.Orders.stats();
{
  size: 14329835,
  count: 10571,
  avgObjSize: 1355,
  storageSize: 4952064,
  freeStorageSize: 307200,
  capped: false
  nindexes: 2,
  indexBuilds: [],
  totalIndexSize: 466944,
  totalSize: 5419008,
  indexSizes: { _id_: 299008, status_1__created_at_1: 167936 },
  scaleFactor: 1,
  ok: 1,
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1635415716, i: 1 })
}
```

Comment: In general, the aggregation stages `$match` and `$sort` when used at the beginning of the pipeline can take advantage of the indexes defined on the fields used in these stages. You can verify the usage of the indexes by generating a _query plan_, using the `explain()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with rewriting the query a little bit to make it more efficient.
Currently you're matching all the orders with a certain status and after that you're starting with data manipulations, this means every single stage is doing work on a larger than needed data set.

What we can do is move all the queries into the first stage, this is made possible using Mongo's [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation), like so:

```
{
    '$match': {
        'status': {
            '$nin': [
                'CANCELLED', 'CHECK_OUT',
            ],
        },
        'products.sku': '3516215049767', // mongo allows you to do this using the dot notation.
        'products.1': { $exists: true }, // this requires the array to have at least two elements.
    },
},
```

Now this achieves two things:

1. We start the pipeline only with relevant results, no need to calculate the `$size` of the array anymore to many unrelevant documents. This already will boost your performance greatly.
2. Now we can create a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/) that will support this specific query, before we couldn't do that as index usage is limited to the first step and that only included the `status` field. ( just as an anecdote is that Mongo actually does optimize pipelines, but in this specific case no optimization was possible to to the usage of `$addFields` )

The index that I recommend building is:

```
{ status: 1, "products.sku": 1 }
```

This will allow the best match to start off your pipeline.

Comment: Outstanding answer! thanks a lot, I didn't know about the dot notation, it's indeed way more elegant.